# Issues with redirect code

Tags: html, wordpress, loops, redirect

When people visit my main page, index.php, I want them to be redirected to index.php?page_id=2

To do this, I added a simple html code in the head:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.domain.com/index.php?page_id=2">
```

The problem is that the destination and all other pages of my site runs that code it goes on a loop. I am using Wordpress. Is there any solution to direct them to index.php?page_id=2 upon visiting index.php without it going on a loop?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid infinite loops, just check if the $_GET variable is empty. If so, do a redirect:

```
if (empty($_GET))
{
    header('Location: index.php?page_id=2');
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, did not work. Are you certain that you wrote it correctly? I added it at the top of the script...

Comment: I received a "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by" error...

Comment: This should be the first thing after the PHP opening <?php
I didn't test it with Wordpress, just using an ordinary PHP file.
If you are including other files before, that might be the reason for the "headers already sent" error.

Comment: It worked now, I had to add the code somewhere else as the structure of the wordpress editor resembles the Star Trek tricorder. Nonetheless, thank you very much for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally you need to make sure that your "meta refresh" is not inserted when index.php has arguments (such as page_id) on its query string.

If you were just doing this in PHP, you would write an if statement inspecting the contents of the querystring using the $_GET hashtable, i.e. if $_GET["page_id"] ...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

In wordpress (which I know less about), you may find a different solution altogether is what you want. For instance, a meta-refresh is actually considered inferior to what's called an HTTP redirect - a header which has the same effect.

In PHP, it is:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php

I notice that the wordpress documentation contains references to redirect utilities; I tried to provide the links, but StackOverflow blocked me from including any more. A search for "redirect" within their documentation may be helpful.

In general, I would expect to see an if statement that decides whether or not to issue a redirect, either using PHP's mechanism, or Wordpress'.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Excellent reply David. Could you kindly provide me with the IF php code to make the redirect? I have no experience in PHP, only html I'm afraid.